# How to correctly retrieve data from local storage?

Tags: javascript

This should be a reservation system. On button click my data are entering correctly in localStorage but when I reload the page the UI change to default but data are still in localStorage. I think I almost tried everythink many tutorials and so on but still failure. Is there a way how to display them after refresh ?

```js
var span = document.querySelector('#pocet');
var badge = document.querySelector('#badge').classList.add('badge-success');
var lock = document.querySelector('#lock');

let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];

localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));


function rezervacka(){
    badge = document.querySelector('#badge');
    lock = document.querySelector('#lock');
    span = document.querySelector('#pocet');
    
    var currentVal = Number(pocet.textContent.split('/')[0]);
    if(currentVal < 7) {
        pocet.textContent = (currentVal + 1) + '/' + 7;
        console.log(pocet);
    }

    if(pocet.textContent === '7/7') {
        badge.classList.add('badge-danger');
        lock.classList.add('fa-lock');
        lock.classList.remove('fa-unlock');
    }

    itemsArray.push(pocet.textContent);
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/90e4bc8c6b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <caption>
            Pondelok,
            16.12.2019 <br />
        </caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Čas</th>
                <th>Workout</th>
                <th>Obsadenosť</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        </tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                07:00 -
                07:50
            </td>
            <td>Powercore Workout s Marcelom</td>
            <td>
                <div id="badge" class="badge"> <i id="lock" class="fa fa-unlock"></i>&nbsp;<span id="pocet">0/7</span>
                </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="marcel1" onclick="rezervacka(this);">Reserve</button>

            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                11:00 -
                11:50
            </td>
            <td>Powercore Workout s Marcelom</td>
            <td>

                <div class="badge badge-success"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> 1/7
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                17:00 -
                17:50
            </td>
            <td>Powercore Workout so Samom</td>
            <td>

                <div class="badge badge-success"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> 2/7
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                18:00 -
                18:50
            </td>
            <td>Powercore Workout so Samom Level 1 Zaciatocnici</td>
            <td>

                <div class="badge badge-success"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> 3/7
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The way you have the localstorage looks okay.   You need a page onload() function to reuse the stored data to update your UI back to it's previous state.   Otherwise the UI will simply be the same on startup.

Comment: any code suqestions please :/

Comment: I agree with @vhoang, figure out a way to call a function _on page load_ that grabs the localStorage data and updates the UI accordingly.

Comment: Can you please suggest some code that will help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are people commenting but not giving you any code? You've obviously actually put in some real effort and just hit a wall. Anyway, your variable `pocet` was never actually defined. I think you called the variable `span`, and that's what you were meaning to reference, so I changed that for you. Then, I added this block of code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    if(itemsArray.length > 0){
        document.querySelector('#pocet').innerHTML = itemsArray[itemsArray.length - 1];
    }
});
```

which waits for the page to load and then updates the pocet span based on the array grabbed from your localStorage. I'm not sure why you need this to be an array rather than a single value, but I left it like that in case you actually need it that way. I also removed the `this` parameter from your `rezervacka(this)` onclick call because you weren't using it. Other than that, I just did some minimal cleaning. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/90e4bc8c6b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script>
            let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];
            localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
            const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));

            window.addEventListener('load', function (){
                if(itemsArray.length > 0){
                    document.querySelector('#pocet').innerHTML = itemsArray[itemsArray.length - 1];
                }
            });

            function rezervacka(){
                badge = document.querySelector('#badge');
                lock = document.querySelector('#lock');
                span = document.querySelector('#pocet');

                var currentVal = Number(span.textContent.split('/')[0]);
                if(currentVal < 7) {
                   span.textContent = (currentVal + 1) + '/' + 7;
                   console.log(pocet);
                }

                if(span.textContent === '7/7') {
                      badge.classList.add('badge-danger');
                      lock.classList.add('fa-lock');
                      lock.classList.remove('fa-unlock');
                }

                itemsArray.push(span.textContent);
                localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <caption>
                Pondelok,
                16.12.2019 <br />
            </caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Čas</th>
                    <th>Workout</th>
                    <th>Obsadenosť</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    07:00 -
                    07:50
                </td>
                <td>Powercore Workout s Marcelom</td>
                <td>
                    <div id="badge" class="badge"> <i id="lock" class="fa fa-unlock"></i>&nbsp;<span id="pocet">0/7</span>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="marcel1" onclick="rezervacka();">Reserve</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    11:00 -
                    11:50
                </td>
                <td>Powercore Workout s Marcelom</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="badge badge-success"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> 1/7
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    17:00 -
                    17:50
                </td>
                <td>Powercore Workout so Samom</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="badge badge-success"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> 2/7
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    18:00 -
                    18:50
                </td>
                <td>Powercore Workout so Samom Level 1 Zaciatocnici</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="badge badge-success"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> 3/7
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need to have ALL buttons save to localStorage, you can give each pocet an ID and then pass that ID to the rezervacka function:

```
rezervacka(pocetID)
```

Then, you can find your elements with that ID, like so:

```
pocet = document.getElementById(pocetID);
badge = pocet.parentNode;
lock = badge.getElementsByClassName("fa")[0];
```

Then, when you're updating localStorage, use an object instead of an array. It's easier that way. You can just save the ID as a key for the textContent value, like this:

```
itemsObject[pocetID] = pocet.textContent;
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsObject));
```

And of course, when you're reloading the page and grabbing the saved localStorage data, you'll grab the data from the object, check to make sure an element with each ID exists, and then update that element with the save value, like so:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    for(var pocetID in itemsObject){
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(itemsObject, pocetID) && document.getElementById(pocetID)){
            document.getElementById(pocetID).innerHTML = itemsObject[pocetID];
        }
    }
});
```

And here is all of that put together in your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/90e4bc8c6b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script>
            let itemsObject = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : {};

            window.addEventListener('load', function (){
                for(var pocetID in itemsObject){
                    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(itemsObject, pocetID) && document.getElementById(pocetID)){
                        document.getElementById(pocetID).innerHTML = itemsObject[pocetID];
                    }
                }
            });

            function rezervacka(pocetID){
                pocet = document.getElementById(pocetID);
                badge = pocet.parentNode;
                lock = badge.getElementsByClassName("fa")[0];

                var currentVal = Number(pocet.textContent.split('/')[0]);
                if(currentVal < 7) {
                   pocet.textContent = (currentVal + 1) + '/' + 7;
                   console.log(pocet);
                }

                if(pocet.textContent === '7/7') {
                      badge.classList.add('badge-danger');
                      lock.classList.add('fa-lock');
                      lock.classList.remove('fa-unlock');
                }

                itemsObject[pocetID] = pocet.textContent;
                localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsObject));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <caption>
                Pondelok,
                16.12.2019 <br />
            </caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Čas</th>
                    <th>Workout</th>
                    <th>Obsadenosť</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    07:00 -
                    07:50
                </td>
                <td>Powercore Workout s Marcelom</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="badge"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i>&nbsp;<span class="pocet" id="pocet1">0/7</span>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<button onclick="rezervacka('pocet1');">Reserve</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    11:00 -
                    11:50
                </td>
                <td>Powercore Workout s Marcelom</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="badge badge-success"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> <span class="pocet" id="pocet2">0/7</span>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<button onclick="rezervacka('pocet2');">Reserve</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    17:00 -
                    17:50
                </td>
                <td>Powercore Workout so Samom</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="badge badge-success"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> <span class="pocet" id="pocet3">0/7</span>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<button onclick="rezervacka('pocet3');">Reserve</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    18:00 -
                    18:50
                </td>
                <td>Powercore Workout so Samom Level 1 Zaciatocnici</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="badge badge-success"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> <span class="pocet" id="pocet4">0/7</span>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<button onclick="rezervacka('pocet4');">Reserve</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fine thats working perfectly. And one more question i want to use the button 'reserve' for every row in the table. But if i click on the second one for example it adding count only to first from 0/7 to 1/7 and so on... Should i make a loop for <td> or what should i do ?

Comment: and any suggestions how to save it to DB via AJAX ?

Comment: Thanks and what about that question before?

Comment: you can add ids to each row, pass the id to the rezervacka function as a parameter, use the passed id to update the row, and add an [id, value] array to items array. Then, update the part where you set the innerHTML onload to loop through itemsArray and set the innerHTML of itemsArray[i][0] to itemsArray[i][1]. I'd update the code myself to show you, but I don't have free time right now. If you can give it a shot and show me what you get, I'll help you later with more specifics if you're not all the way there.

Comment: thanks i will try to do it by myself and if i will get stuck i will text you

Comment: I cant move any further, well i will wait for your code explanation. Sorry about that

Comment: Alright I've got some new code for you. Since this is a different question, would you mind making another post so I can give another answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204396/discussion-between-codehysteria-and-aaron-plocharczyk).